# Relationship between GraphicsDevice.Clear's color and the color drawn onto the screen

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, xna-4.0

I am a beginner to XNA and am experimenting with my new kinect for windows so decided to follow a tutorial: http://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/kinect-fundamentals-2-basic-programming/

After doing this one I noticed that all the colors are tinted light blue. For example a color of rgb 20,20,20 will look like dark blue instead of dark gray.

I noticed that the `GraphicsDevice.Clear()` is using `Color.CornflowerBlue`. I experimented with changing it to `Color.Black` and sure enough all the stuff are now tinted black.

What's the relationship between the GraphicsDevice.Clear(color) and the colors being drawn onto the screen?

Here's my draw function:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is called when the game should draw itself.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(kinectRGBVideo, new Rectangle(0, 0, 640, 480), Color.White);
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, connectedStatus, new Vector2(20, 80), Color.Black);
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Try changing the [BlendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.blendstate_members.aspx) at the call of the [spriteBatch.Begin()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433698.aspx) method. This dictates how colors blend when drawn above each other.

Comment: Nice! It worked wonderfully, change it to an answer and I'll accept it. Oh and by the way, do you know why using BlendState.Opaque will cause text to be displayed as blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As requested, in form of an answer.)

Try changing the BlendState at the call of the spriteBatch.Begin() method. This dictates how colors blend when drawn above each other.

I'm not exactly sure why `BlendState.Opaque` displays text as blocks, but my guess is that this blend state does not support alpha. Therefore the transparent regions around the text turn, well, opaque, making the text look like a rectangle. I don't have the tools to check this guess on me right now, so I can verify it.

Comment: That guess makes a lot of sense and is most likely the cause. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're right about `Opaque`. That is exactly what is happening. It's useful for drawing 3D models - not so much for sprites.